# should phrases in a multilanguage site be stored in the database or in files?

Tags: translation, storage, multilingual

I'm developing a website, and want to make multi language support, but I'm doubting where I should store the phrases.

Storing them in a database makes it easier to create systems where you crowdsource the translation, in a similar facion facebook and twitter are doing. The disadvantage is that querying a database for phrases can be slow, especially when there are a lot of phrases on a page.

Storing them in a file makes retrieval faster, but makes them harder to manage and maintain.

What are some other pros and cons?

Comment: "Storing them in a file makes retrieval faster" - depends on your site's load. In my experience, once you get a significant number of concurrent requests, file access will become a significant bottleneck (no matter how fast the disks are).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the phrases need to change often, then store them in a database.  If the phrases change infrequently or never, and you are using java, store them in a resource bundle.

If you are worried about load time from a db, you can cache the phrases and periodically update the cache.